# Get the increase for a prometheus metric that has been recorded as a rate

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let's say I have a metric `foo_count` that get's rolled up before being written to remote storage to reduce cardinality and uses this rule:

```
- record: rollup:foo_count:1m
  expr: sum(rate(foo_count[1m])) without(pod, nodename, instance)
```

How do I get the `24h` total of `rollup:foo_count:1m`? For the raw metric, I know I could simply do `sum(increase(foo_count)[24h])`.

I thought I could use `sum(sum_over_time(rollup:foo_count:1m)[24h])`, but the results are not close at all.

Any ideas on how to write the correct query to get the total of the rollup over the last 24h?

Comment: from your question it's not clear why don't you use the recorded metric `rollup:foo_count:1m`? in both your examples you try the raw metric

Comment: I'll update. The sum_over_time uses the recorded metric

Comment: pls note that you use mix `rate` (in recording rule) and `increase` (in expected)

Comment: That will not work since the recording rule is no longer a counter but a rate. Its not increasing and there are no resets to account for.

Comment: yes u're right, I'll rm it to not to confuse other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out with `avg_over_time`:

```
sum(avg_over_time(rollup:foo_count:1m[24h])) * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Basically, you average the rate out over the period... then multiple it by the number of seconds in the same period

Comment: do you mean `foo_count` --> `rollup:foo_count:1m`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I keep messing up copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your `sum_over_time` approach is that is sums samples that are present every `evaluation_interval` seconds. Where `rate` is a "per-second average rate of increase of the time series".

Thus `sum_over_time` will differ by factor of `evaluation_interval`.

You can see in [this demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=%20%20%20%20%20sum_over_time(%20instance%3Anode_vmstat_pgmajfault%3Arate5m%20%20%5B24h%5D%20)*15%20*%20on()%20group_left(type)%20absent(non_existent%7Btype%3D%22sum_over_time%22%7D)%0Aor%20(avg_over_time(%20instance%3Anode_vmstat_pgmajfault%3Arate5m%20%20%5B24h%5D%20)*24*60*60%20*%20on()%20group_left(type)%20absent(non_existent%7Btype%3D%22avg_over_time%22%7D))%0Aor%20(increase(node_vmstat_pgmajfault%7Bjob%3D%22node%22%7D%5B24h%5D)%20*%20on()%20group_left(type)%20absent(non_existent%7Btype%3D%22original%22%7D)%20)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=6h&g1.expr=instance%3Anode_vmstat_pgmajfault%3Arate5m%20%20%5B24h%5D&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h) (where `evaluation_interval` is set to 15s) that `increase(metric [24h])` produces almost the same result as both `sum_over_time(instance:metric:rate5m [24h]) * 15` and `avg_over_time(instance:metric:rate5m [24h]) * 24*60*60`. Slight difference in graphs is explained by `increase` having immediate effect on metric spiking change, while rate over 5 minutes "flattens the curve" a bit.